# How do I associate an email address with an account?

Tags: email, custom-field, account

I have emails associated only with accounts that I would like to import to salesforce. How does one add custom field to an account, and does this then appear in the import wizard?

Comment: OK, I discovered the solution: For adding a custom field, follow [this](https://eu2.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/adding_fields.htm) howto.
The custom fields appear in the import wizard.

Comment: If you have answered your own question, you can post it (after 2 days) as an answer. Please do this so we can keep the format of SE as a Q&A site

Comment: ok, done, I just had to wait 8 hours to be able to post an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I discovered the solution: For adding a custom field, follow [this](https://eu2.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/adding_fields.htm) howto.
The custom fields appear in the import wizard.